# Running java process command using Tomcat-7

Tags: java, tomcat, processbuilder

I am using Java-7 and process builder to run shell script using Tomcat 7.

```
processBuilder =    new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "/opt/script.sh");
processBuilder.start();
```

As the above mention code invoked via JSP page hosted by Tomcat7 Server, so the command run but process is not able to continue as it is initiated by tomcat7 user (Default user of tomcat) How can i run this command as root, assuming i know root password?

Comment: I would suggest to never run a process from a Jsp page. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command using [sudo](https://www.linux.com/learn/linux-101-introduction-sudo):

> Effectively, sudo allows a user to run a program as another user (most
>   often the root user).

```
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", "echo <password> | sudo -S /opt/script.sh");
b.start();
```

Comment: From the above code, where the user id "root" is mentioned. Wondering what makes process builder to use username root for given password?

Comment: As I said, the fact that you're using [sudo](https://www.linux.com/learn/linux-101-introduction-sudo) makes the process execute as the super user (root).